# How to set Java EE security roles

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, roles

I'm working on a filter to be put in front of a Java application. This filter already is responsible for setting the user name in the remote user variable (in order for the application to do a request.getRemoteUser() call).

I'd like to also set the roles of the currently logged user from a custom call to an LDAP (not requesting user groups but other specific attributes).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you write a custom LoginModule, you can authenticate the user yourself, as well as populate the user's roles based on what is in LDAP.  If you specify your application server, I could provide more specific information.

Answer (score 0):

OK, LoginModule. It looks like it's what I was looking for... (Filter does not provide the needed functionalities regarding EJB, only servlets)
What specificities are they between different App Servers? Isn't there a core Java EE LoginModule specification that is suported by all servers? (at least WAS and jBoss I would say)

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: >Isn't there a core Java EE LoginModule specification that is suported by all servers? - Actually there is. It's called JASPIC, and is theoretically supported by all full Java EE 6 servers.